# What is the variance of the error term used by the logit command in stata?

Tags: stata, logit

I would like to compare the coefficients from the same model estimated by the logit and probit command. I think that the probit model is estimated normalizing the variance of the error term to 1. What is the variance of the error term used by the logit command in STATA?

Comment: Why not compare marginal effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\pi^2}{3}$$ However, it is best to use a conversion factor of 1.6. Amemiya's [Qualitative Response Models](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2724565) is a good read for this topic. The conversion factor is only approximate and can perform badly in certain situations $-$ such as when modeling extreme probabilities. If you want to compare models, it is best to compare predicted probabilities.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious why this number is not included in the STATA manual.

Comment: I do not use Stata. It is possibly because it is more natural to derive logistic regression without considering error variance. The most common alternative formulation is the generalized linear model formulation. In fact, some users of CV will often reply that "the logistic regression model has no error term", because thinking about it as having error terms is unnecessary, plus the logistic distribution is not a common distribution. Probit uses standard normal which can be justified based on central limit theorem.

Comment: I find it natural to think about error term in multinomial logit models. And this makes the binary logit model a special case.

Comment: @YanSong there are again people who have no exposure to error terms for multinomial or ordinal models. Those models are simply multivariate generalized linear models.

Comment: Sure. But it does not mean it's really the best way to view these models. There are many instances where ignoring the error term will make serious mistakes interpreting model outcomes.

Comment: @YanSong I was not making the claim that it is a superior way to view the models. In fact, certain forms of model misspecification are more readily understood when you use latent variables composed of error term. But I'm not aware of when ignoring it will cause mistakes of interpretation.

Comment: You can read Kenneth Train's book for reference.

Comment: @YanSong since it's a book, can you provide more information, like a page number? It's a free resource so I'm glad to look it up.

Comment: Sure. Section 2.5 in chapter 2.